# JPA delete @ManyToOne Entity on EAGER collection

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

Very simple problem, but it looks like is impossible to achieve what I want

The entities:

```
public class C {

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "column")
   private Set<B> cards = new HashSet<>();
}

public class B {

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
   @JsonIgnore
   @JoinColumn(name="column_id", nullable = false)
   private C column;

}

@Repository
public interface BRepository extends JpaRepository<B, Long> {

}
```

I want to delete the B entity without use the C Repository.
if I do something like:

```
  final C column = columnService.create(board, new C(board, "column name", 1)); //works
  final B card = cardService.create(column, new B(column, "card name", 2)); //works
  
  bRepository.delete(card); //NOTHING HAPPENS
```

Absolutely nothing happens on delete query, no log, data isn't removed from DB, nothing.... doesn't matter if I'm within or out a @transaction.

WHAT I'VE TRIED:

1 - if i change Set cards to FetchType.LAZY, the delete works, [but i really wanted it to be eager]
2 - if create a custom query on repository like:

```
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM Card c where c.id = :id")
public void deleteById(@Param("id") long id);
```

then the delete works BUT, I've `EntityListeners` for this entity, and as per JPA documentation it wont work on custom query... so i need this component working

Is there a way to delete the ONE side of relationship with EAGER fetch without custom query and without loading the other side of relationship?

Comment: Providing a full minimal reproducible example will most likely help to get you the answer faster.

Comment: this is a full minimal reproducible example... i just didnt write main